# How to query specific duplicate values utilizing a union with CTEs

Tags: sql, duplicates, union, common-table-expression

Having trouble with a query I am building. My goal is to create an output that meets the condition's of both CTEs, and then combine the output where it only shows the IDs where they are true for both CTE conditions. I am not sure I need the row number over partition clause in the CTEs, but I think I need something to designate the duplicate values, duplicate values being the IDs that are present in both CTEs.

The snippet below is taking the output from a longer query that gives me a complete population:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
        (SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY DATE) AS RN --row number
        FROM #complete_query_output
        WHERE Decision = 'Declined'
        AND xyz> 0 
        AND (Business_Rule_1= 1 OR Business_Rule_2= 1 OR Business_Rule_3= 1)
        ),
 
CTE2 AS
        (SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY DATE) AS RN
        FROM #complete_query_output
        WHERE abc = 1
        --AND Decision = 'Approved'
        )

SELECT *
FROM CTE1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM CTE2

ORDER BY ID
```

I've tried adding in something like the below but I'm not getting the desired output as the ID field is not showing IDs that are in both fields.

```
SELECT *, count(*)
FROM CTE1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *, count(*)
FROM CTE2

GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Look at *INTERSECT*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like

```
SELECT id, count(*)
(
SELECT id
FROM CTE1

UNION ALL

SELECT id
FROM CTE2
)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This gets all the `id`s from your two CTEs (combines then with the `union all`), then the outer query groups by them and counts them.

As you alluded to, applying the `group by` and `having` to the individual CTEs doesn't help since it doesn't account for the total count of them combined.

Edited to add, as Stu mentioned in the comments you could use `intersect`. This is cleaner than what I suggested above, if you just want to identify cases where a row exists in both queries:

Something like:

```
SELECT id
FROM CTE1
INTERSECT
SELECT id
FROM CTE2
```

This doesn't return the counts (unclear if that's a requirement) and could return different results than what I originally suggested. If CTE1 has 2 rows with `ID`=1 and CTE2 has 0 rows with `ID`=1, my first query would count that as a duplicate, but the `INTERSECT` query would not, so you need to understand your data and what you want in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

To identify IDs that are present in both CTEs, I suggest using `inner join` :

```
WITH CTE1 AS
        ....
),
CTE2 AS (
        ....
)
SELECT c1.id
FROM CTE1 c1
INNER JOIN CTE2 c2 on c1.id = c2.id
```